# Cmake: How to force a compiler only if present?

Tags: cmake

I would like Cmake to use Intel C++ Compiler *only* if it is present. I found this snippet on here, but, as the name suggests, it forces Cmake to use Intel compiler. And will complain if not present. Period.

```
include(CMakeForceCompiler)
CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER(icc "Intel C Compiler")
CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER(icpc "Intel C++ Compiler")
```

Is there any way to achieve this kind of behaviour (ideally *only* displaying a warning to the user if not present)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible from inside CMake.

CMake expects the user to setup and select the correct toolchain. Then on the first configure run CMake performs a couple of tests to verify that the selected compiler is present and works as expected. This check can only be performed once per configure, so a clean switch of compilers from within CMake always requires wiping the CMakeCache.txt and restarting with a fresh configure run.

You will need an external script that selects the correct compiler and then invokes CMake with the correct parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it:

```
find_program (INTEL_COMPILER icc)
if (INTEL_COMPILER)
  include (CMakeForceCompiler)
  cmake_force_c_compiler (icc "Intel C Compiler")
  cmake_force_cxx_compiler (icpc "Intel C++ Compiler")
endif (INTEL_COMPILER)
```

So here, CMake doesn't say anything if you don't have Intel compiler, but you could easily add a `message("You don't have icc in your PATH")` in the `else()` branch!